# Is it possible to edit a list in a json file?

Tags: json, python-3.x, list

I am trying to append to a list in json file please see below example.

```
filename = websites.json

{"id": "json_key", "website": ["amazon.com", "facebook.com", "google.com"]}
```

For example, I want to add another website to the "website" list using user input and sort them by alphabetical order.

```
Ex.
user input: quora.com

Output:
{"id": "json_key", "website": ["amazon.com", "facebook.com", "google.com", "quora.com"]}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. Json load the file, modify the object, Json write the file again.

Comment: how to modify the object I've only seen here the appending of another key value but not appending to an existing list.

Comment: You load the file into an object, then modifiy the object, then write the modified object into a new/the same file.